# Intent getExtras returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I have three activities A, B and C. Lets say the task is in foreground with the stack(A->B->C).

Now when a notification is clicked, I start activity A with intent flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and pass extra information with intent.

```
Intent AIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
AIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
AIntent.putExtra(Constants.IntentFields.FROM_NOTI, true);
AIntent.putExtra(Constants.IntentFields.GROUP_POS, groupActive);
AIntent.putExtra(Constants.IntentFields.CHILD_POS, childPos);
```

,

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Intent AIntent)
{
    int requestCode = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(delegate, requestCode, AIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

Now A's oncreate is called, here I call getIntent and check the extra information to see if it was triggered from notification. If yes I start B with an intent by passing some extra information again.

```
//in A's onCreate()
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras!=null && extras.getBoolean(Constants.IntentFields.FROM_NOTI) && Delegate.INSTANCE.isLoggedIn())
{
    Intent BIntent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(Constants.IntentFields.FROM_NOTI, true);
    bundle.putInt(Constants.IntentFields.GROUP_POS, extras.getInt(Constants.IntentFields.GROUP_POS));
    bundle.putInt(Constants.IntentFields.CHILD_POS, extras.getInt(Constants.IntentFields.CHILD_POS));

    BIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(BIntent);
}
```

Now on B's onCreate() when I call getIntent(), the returned intent does not contained the extra information I passed from A.

```
//called from B's onCreate
private void checkIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(extras!=null && extras.getBoolean(Constants.IntentFields.FROM_NOTI))
    {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "From noti");
        startC(extras);
    }
}
```

How can I access the new intent that starts the activity B? I tried onNewIntent(), but that isn't called.

Comment: Has activity B neen actually recreated? You can log its lifecycle events (like `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onStart`) to make out what happens with it.

Comment: Yes, B's onCreate() gets called. That is where I call getIntent() and intent does not have the extras.